# C: Soma entre dois números retorna valor do ASCII ou letra

Tags: c

Galera, sou iniciante na linguagem C, tô fazendo um desafio e empaquei em uma parte do código.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long long n = get_long_long("Number: ");

char card_number[15];
sprintf(card_number, "%lld", n);
int length_number = strlen(card_number);


for(int i = 0; i < length_number; i++)
{
        printf("A soma entre %c e %c é: %i \n", (int) card_number[i], (int)card_number[i], (int)(card_number[i] * 2));

}

printf("%s\n", card_number);
```

O método `get_long_long` é de uma biblioteca externa, do CS50 pra ser mais exata. Ele guarda na variável o que o usuário escreveu no prompt de acordo com o que foi solicitado (`"Number: "`).

Supondo que o `card_number[i]` é igual a dois, na hora de multiplicar ele acaba entendendo esse 2 como 50 (2 na tabela ASCII é igual a 50) e o resultado dá 100, quando na verdade deveria dar 4! Já tentei de várias formas e nada! Dependendo do tipo de `%` que eu coloco, ele muda o valor da soma para uma letra. Quero muito resolver e entender o porquê disso.

Answer (score 1):

Não está muito claro no seu código o que é que você queria fazer. Mas uma forma de converter um caractere na faixa `0`-`9` para o equivalente numérico é fazer isso:

```
numero = caractere - '0';
```

No caso, o `'0'` é 48 de acordo com a tabela ASCII. No entanto, ao usar `- '0'`, o propósito do código fica mais de se entender do que colocar um `- 48`.

Assim sendo, talvez o que você queria é isso:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length_number; i++) {
    printf("A soma entre %c e %c é: %i \n",
            card_number[i], card_number[i], (card_number[i] - '0') * 2);
}
```

Quando você usa `%c`, o `printf` mostra o valor dado como um caractere de acordo com a tabela ASCII. O valor dado é **sempre** um número e a tabela é usada apenas e somente para encontrar o caractere correspondente a esse número. Já quando você usa `%i` ou `%d`, o valor é interpretado como um `int` e expresso com a notação decimal.

Veja mais sobre os modificadores [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).